# Symfony2 - EntityRepository - Sorting rows - is this a good and save approach?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine created a repository for my class and to get a list of all elements sorted by any row, I wrote this member:

```
class NoteRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function findAllOrderedByRow($row, $order = 'ASC') {
        if ( 'DESC' != strtoupper($order) ) {
            $order  = 'ASC';
        }

        if ( property_exists('Namespace\Entity', $row) ) {
            return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery('SELECT o FROM Entity o ORDER BY o. ' . $row . ' ' . $order)
                ->getResult();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

My question is, whether this is a good approach or is it better to add functions for all rows that are sortable? And is it save, to use it like that? I don't see a way for an injection. But maybe I overlooked it.

Many thanks,
Philipp

Comment: When using programmatically generated queries I'd go for the `QueryBuilder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function available in the EntityRepository called `findBy`. You can pass the order by as second parameter.

```
public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
```

And a little example :

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('User')->findBy(
    array(), 
    array('email' => 'asc')
);
```

Overriding this behaviour is in my point of view useless.

Comment: Many thanks - you're absolutely right. Again I overlooked a very cool build in feature. Thanks for the hint.